# The number 2 in Deviance

Tags: aic, deviance

What is the additional coefficient 2 in AIC, or other deviance criteria? In the books or on the internet I keep reading "historical reasons". What the heck are those historical reasons? Is there a merit for the 2 keep appearing?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_(statistics)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion

Clearly the correct deviance for $AIC$ is $LogLikelihood - k$. Not only that it is negated it is also scaled by 2 in presentations:

$AIC=-2LogLikelihood + 2k$

But then to fix it in relative likelihood we divide by 2.

$Relative Likelihood = e^{(AIC_{min}−AIC_i)/2}$

Thanks

Comment: I'm too lazy to dig through it myself right now, but you'll probably find your answer in the original AIC publication: http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/Jon/MiscDocs/Akaike_1974.pdf

Comment: Note that the AIC is based on an an asymptotic argument, originally one relating to regression models. If I recall correctly (and I may not, it's been a long while) the $-2$ is there basically because of the $-\frac{1}{2}$ in the exponent of an asymptotic normal distribution. It's not really necessary, and I've seen some people work with [AIC half that of the usual](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~dschmidt/ModelSectionTutorial1_SchmidtMakalic_2008.pdf) (see p31). The adjustment term at the end of the AIC is there to (asymptotically) adjust for the bias introduced by maximizing the likelihood.

Comment: (ctd) ... the $-2\log \cal{L}$ is often of particularly simple form for a number of common models.